# Upgrading my Spring WebFlow projects to use Maven and Hibernate4. Now Gets NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-webflow

I have to upgrade my projects to start using Hibernate4 and Maven for the build.  I have a number of projects and this process is killing me with the error.  My Projects are Spring WebFlow, MySQL, CAS and Hibernate4 it was using Hibernate3 without any issues.

I made the pom.xml to the best I could do but it looks like I maybe having Hibernate versioning issues.  I am getting the following error:

***NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass***

I think my project can be trying to use Hibernate3 still and not Hibernate4.  If you review my pom.xml below you will see I am requesting Hibernate4 but if you look in my WAR file after the packaging you can see Hibernate4 and Hibernate3 libs.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/database-c3p0.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:259)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected method not found: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(java.lang.Class)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod(ClassUtils.java:627)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<clinit>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:68)
    ... 69 more
Sep 14, 2012 8:08:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```

Here is my pox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.uftwf.schoolvisit</groupId>
    <artifactId>SchoolVisit</artifactId>
    <name>School Visit</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.5</java-version>
        <springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</springframework-version>
        <springwebflow-version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</springwebflow-version>
        <springsecurity-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <!-- will come with all needed Spring dependencies such as spring-core 
                and spring-beans -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>${springwebflow-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF-303 Dependency Injection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Sun Mojarra JSF 2 runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSR 303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
            ** HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Hibernate Validator -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Sun Mojarra JSF 2 implementation -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For PrimeFaces JSF component library -->

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>SchoolVisit</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the list of files in my lib in my WAR from maven:

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.1.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar
aspectjtools-1.6.2.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
c3p0-0.9.2-pre4.jar
cal10n-api-0.7.2.jar
cas-client-core-3.1.10.jar
cas-client-core-3.1.12.jar
cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar
cglib-2.2.2.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-dbcp.jar
commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dumbster-1.6.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-search-3.0.0.GA.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
httpclient-4.1.2.jar
httpclient-4.2.1.jar
httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.2.1.jar
httpmime-4.1.2.jar
icu4j-2.6.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.5.3.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.3.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.servlet-jstl-1.2.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jaxen-1.1.1.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.10.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
joda-time-1.6.jar
joda-time-jsptags-1.0.2.jar
jsf-api-2.1.7.jar
jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jstl-jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
list.txt
log4j-1.2.14.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
lucene-core-2.3.2.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.0.0.jar
mail-1.4.5.jar
mail-1.4.jar
mailapi.jar
mail.jar
mchange-commons-java-0.2.2.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.binding-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.faces-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js.resources-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.webflow-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar
slf4j-ext-1.5.10.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar
smtp.jar
spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-binding-2.3.1.BUILD-20120326.222602-13.jar
spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-faces-2.3.1.BUILD-20120326.222626-13.jar
spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-js-2.3.1.BUILD-20120326.222614-13.jar
spring-js-resources-2.3.1.BUILD-20120326.222607-13.jar
spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE-all.jar
spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-cas-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-cas-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-cas-client-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-openid-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-remoting-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webflow-2.3.1.BUILD-20120326.222621-13.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
tiles-api-2.1.3.jar
tiles-core-2.1.3.jar
tiles-jsp-2.1.3.jar
tiles-servlet-2.1.3.jar
urlrewritefilter-3.1.0.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
xalan-2.6.0.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
xom-1.0.jar
```

as you can see my POM.XML is importing many version of the same file and I think this maybe the issues but I dont know. Being new to maven and Hibernate4 I dont know the real isssue.  Looking forward to hearing some feelback... thanks

Here is the output from my mvn dependency:tree but I still dont see where Hibernate3 is coming from:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building School Visit 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ SchoolVisit ---
[INFO] org.uftwf.schoolvisit:SchoolVisit:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js-resources:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas-client:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jasig.cas:cas-client-core:jar:3.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.21:compile
[INFO] +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.cal10n:cal10n-api:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.291s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 14 09:06:33 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/162M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it.  I created a new maven webapp and copied in the pom.xml and the source and everything is great...

Comment: the key word you're looking for is mvn 'clean'. the old jars have to be purged from the lib. starting a new webapp is the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to solve this kind of problems is to run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and analyze its output in order to find where wrong versions of dependencies come from, then fix them by applying necessary exclusions.

However, in your case output of `mvn dependency:tree` doesn't contain anything wrong. Therefore I think that you have stale versions of dependencies in your `target` folder, therefore you need to run `mvn clean` to remove them.

Comment: I just did a mvn clean and package and I can see that its still importing all the same files.  which I think maybe the issue.

Comment: @techsjs2012: Are you sure you don't have these jars somewhere is `src`, for example, in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib`?

Answer (score 0):

As someone else noted, run "mvn dependency:tree" to see where the hibernate 3 dependency is picked up from.  You can then exclude it in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>           
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Going from hibernate 3 to 4 also requires changing from AnnotationSessionFactoryBean in the hibernate3 package to the LocalSessionFactoryBean in the hibernate4 package, and using the transaction manager in the hibernate4 package.

What was once two separate beans in the hibernate3 package (local and annotation) has become a single bean in the hibernate4 package, and you cannot use the hibernate3 package if you have upgraded.

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/

Comment: thanks matt I did see the migrating and I did change the to LocalSessionFactoryBean... but I think its a maven issue